# Is there any way to capture this specific city?

Tags: endless-legend

[image]

This city is surrounded by districts on 3 sides, water on 2 and a temple on the last. Autopathing on an attack loads my army into a boat that just sits off the coast because they can't land. Is there anyway at all to capture this city?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you have to attack the "city center" tile itself to engage in an attack on the city - I think, as the hero standing there, that it would suffice to attack the borough tile, and that would initiate a combat against the city.

However, as you're suggesting there are definitely some serious bugs in their random-map-generator, mostly due to the whole way they've designed embarking, and the lack of water combat - which result in inaccessible strips of land trapped behind a single ruin/village - which is most problematic when it literally prevents you from doing a crucial quest (there will often be a minor-faction-unit stuck back there, sitting on a single tile you can't disembark onto because it's already occupied).

There's also just a general design flaw in the way that coastal edges of a city are not attackable - if you get a small city on an island, and perfectly fill the whole island, it's impregnable because there's nowhere to disembark.

You're not the only person to run into this - so if it looks like a bug hosing your ability to do something, it just might be.

Comment: I can attack the city no problem, but I can't actually capture it. Basically it means build costal cities and surround them with districts and you literally cannot lose the game.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't make much sense to me - the only two operations you can do against a city are either to besiege it, or to attack it - if you attack it, it starts a battle, and if the battle is won, the city is immediately captured.  An attack is possible to initiate against any borough tile, not just the city center.  --  I can understand if you can siege a city and not attack/capture it, but I can't understand "can attack but not capture" since afaict they're the same action.

Comment: No , your right, I can't seige it, and the defenders can come out and fight me, but I can't initiate a fight with them

Comment: Honestly from looking at your screenshot, it doesn't look like the map layout is preventing you from attacking.  I can see the crossed-swords "attack" icon in your hero's loadout - I can understand that if you used that command against the city center tile, you'd get weird pathing failures - but don't use it against that.  You **should** be able to issue the attack command against the borough tile immediately adjacent to the north-west of your hero - like actually click on *that tile*, not the city name or anything.

Comment: If you're doing that, and it *still* won't let you, then it's a legit bug, and there have been a few bits of weirdness like that (moreso in the past, but there are still some warts like this they seriously need to iron out).

Answer (score -4):

Capture it during winter, when the water is frozen.